# How to solve error "SyntaxError: Unexpected token '?'"

Tags: node.js, discord.js

I'm not sure what's wrong. I deleted my code and downloaded it then uploaded it again and now I get this error.

Code: https://replit.com/@hi12167pies/webcord#index.js (Click code for code and output for output)

Error:

```
/home/runner/C8AU9ceLyjc/node_modules/discord.js/src/rest/RESTManager.js:32
    const token = this.client.token ?? this.client.accessToken;
                                     ^

SyntaxError: Unexpected token '?'
```

I have no idea whats wrong since it's in the node_modules folder.

If you have problems viewing it here is the code:

```
const http = require("http")
const discord = require("discord.js")
const client = new discord.Client()
const config = require("./config.json")
const fs = require("fs")
// const readLine = require("readline")
// const rl = readLine.createInterface({
//   input: process.stdin,
//   output: process.stdout
// })

let msgs = {
  "873195510251532348": [],
  "873195522633105429": []
}


client.on("ready", () => {
  console.log("ready discord")
})

client.on("message", (message) => {
  if (message.author.bot) return
  if (!config.chats.includes(message.channel.id.toString())) return

  msgs[message.channel.id].push({
    "username": message.author.tag,
    "content": message.content,
    "type": "0"
  })
})

http.createServer((req,res) => {
  const url = req.url.split("?")[0]
  let query = {}
  req.url.slice(req.url.split("").indexOf("?")).slice(1).split("&").forEach((e) => {
    const splited = e.split("=")
    query[splited[0]] = splited[1]
  })

  if (query.q == "messages") {
    let msg = []

    let i = 0
    while (msgs[query.code].length > i) {
      const e = msgs[query.code][msgs[query.code].length - (i+1)]
      msg.push(e)
      i++
    }

    res.write(JSON.stringify(msg))
    res.end()
  } else if (query.q == "post") {
    let name = query.name.split("%20").join(" ")
    let content = query.content.split("%20").join(" ")
    client.channels.cache.get(query.code).send(`**${name}**: ${content}`)
    msgs[query.code].push({
      "username": name,
      "content": content,
      "type": "1"
    })
    res.end()
  } else if (url == "/robot" && query.istrue == "true") {
    res.write("Robot!")
    res.end()
  } else {
    let path
    if (!query.code) {
      path = "./code.html"
    } else {
      if (!config.chats.includes(query.code)) {
        path = "./invaildcode.html"
      } else {
        path = "./chat.html"
      }
    }
    fs.readFile(path, (er, da) => {
      if (er) res.write("Could not get index.html")
      res.write(da)
      res.end()
    })
  }


}).listen(80, (err) => {
  if (err) throw err
  console.log("listening webserver")
})

client.login(process.env.TOKEN)
```

I am aware my code is not good right now, I am rewriting it but I still want to know what the error is.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

`repl.it` uses `node v12.22.1` but the [nullish coalescing operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Nullish_coalescing_operator) (`??`), is relatively new and was added in `node v14`.

**So to use the `??` operator you need to update `node` in repl.it.**

Which you can do by following [this repl.it forum post](https://replit.com/talk/learn/How-to-update-Nodejs-version/143570) by [lukenzy](https://replit.com/@lukenzy).

> Create a file and name it .replit
> Inside it, copy and paste the following code:
>
> ```
> run = """
> curl -o- https://raw.githubusercontent.com/nvm-sh/nvm/v0.34.0/install.sh |  bash
> export NVM_DIR=\"$HOME/.nvm\"
> [ -s \"$NVM_DIR/nvm.sh\" ] && \\. \"$NVM_DIR/nvm.sh\"
> [ -s \"$NVM_DIR/bash_completion\" ] && \\.\"$NVM_DIR/bash_completion\"
> nvm install 14
> node index.js
> """
> ```
>
> This will install and use the latest Node.js v14 (14.17.4).
> If u want to use a different version, change nvm install 14 to any other
> number.
> Also, change node index.js to the file u want to run.

Comment: This makes sense, but I don't get why it used to work?

Comment: @hi12167pies The new syntax isn't in your code, but in `discord.js` maybe you updated to the latest version of `discord.js` which uses the new syntax?

Comment: Indeed. If you look at the source code of the `RESTManager` of `discord.js` v12 [here](https://github.com/discordjs/discord.js/blob/v12/src/rest/RESTManager.js#L29), you'll see that it used the older way of doing this (`||`) instead of nullish coalescing (`??`). Discord.js v13's use of the newer nullish coalescing and optional chaining operators are why the library requires node.js >=14.x.x to run now.

Comment: in which folder put this new file?

Comment: @SalimMansoori You can create the `.replit` file in the root of your project.

Answer (score 5):

You are getting this error because you are using an older version of node that didn't support nullable for some packages.

Simply change node version of yours.

You can simply change node versions using 'nvm'. follow this git repo https://github.com/nvm-sh/nvm

Answer (score 4):

You need to upgrade to NodeJS version 16 and above for this error to vanish

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please edit to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.

Comment: solved it issue