# SyntaxError: Unexpected token '?' in repl.it since I updated to discord.js V13

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have just started to change my discord bot to discord.js V13 and since all the changes have been made, I can not figure out why this error keeps on coming up.

```
/home/runner/Discordjs-V13/node_modules/discord.js/src/rest/RESTManager.js:32
    const token = this.client.token ?? this.client.accessToken;
                                     ^

SyntaxError: Unexpected token '?'
```

Comment: *"v13 requires Node 16.6 or higher to use, so make sure you're up to date."* — https://discordjs.guide/additional-info/changes-in-v13.html#before-you-start

Comment: replace with: `const token = this.client.token || this.client.accessToken;`

Comment: @Abd I don't think OP will want to edit the source code of a 3rd party library, and this probably won't be the only place which raises errors either.

Comment: @deceze Sorry my bad, didn't realize the error is made by a node_module package, I thought it was his own code.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to solve error "SyntaxError: Unexpected token '?'"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68692038/how-to-solve-error-syntaxerror-unexpected-token)

Answer (score 0):

The **`'??'` operator** is new in the `node v14` version, for Discord.js V13 you need the current version of node.js, but here they explain how to change your node.js version in repl.it, try if it works for u :)

> https://replit.com/talk/learn/Nodejs-14-on-replit/85501

Answer (score 0):

Hmm that's because REPLit don't have updated NodeJS version do one thing
Go to Your shell and paste this and hit enter

```
npm i --save-dev node@16 && npm config set prefix=$(pwd)/node_modules/node && export PATH=$(pwd)/node_modules/node/bin:$PATH
```

And change the start script in pacakge.json to `npm start`

AND BOOM! You have latest node!