# const token = this.client.token ?? this.client.accessToken; SyntaxError: Unexpected token '?' repl.it with latest node

Tags: node.js, discord.js, replit

I have the latest node version installed `v16` and when i start the bot with the run button or the console it brings me this error:

```
const token = this.client.token ?? this.client.accessToken;
                                     ^

SyntaxError: Unexpected token '?'
```

But when using shell and typing in `node index.js` it works fine. So I don't understand what's repl.it so upset about when all is up-to-date?

Comment: _"when i start the bot with the run button or the console"_... could you elaborate on this please? What exactly are you doing to _"start the bot"_?

Comment: Click on the green button that says `run` or typing `node index.js` in the console.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to solve error "SyntaxError: Unexpected token '?'"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68692038/how-to-solve-error-syntaxerror-unexpected-token)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Run `npm install node@16` in shell

Create a file called `.replit`

Inside the .replit file, add `run = "npx node index.js"`. If your main file has a different name change index.js to your main file's name.

Now when you click run, replit uses node.js v16 instead of v12

Comment: This works, but strange. Still don't understand why it's worked with `npm install node@16` when I've tried other methods I've found online too