# Creating my first bot using REPLIT but always error Discord.JS

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, discord.js

I have just started Discord.JS on Replit.
It followed FreeCodeCamp's Tutorial on https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/create-a-discord-bot-with-javascript-nodejs/

But when I runned the code it telled me to run :

```
const Discord = require("discord.js")
const client = new Discord.Client()

client.on("ready", () => {
  console.log(`Logged in as ${client.user.tag}!`)
})

client.on("message", msg => {
  if (msg.content === "ping") {
    msg.reply("pong");
  }
})

client.login(process.env.TOKEN)
```

It tells this error :

```
Error: Cannot find module 'node:events'
Require stack:
- /home/runner/Omega-Flowey-JS-Test/node_modules/discord.js/src/client/BaseClient.js
- /home/runner/Omega-Flowey-JS-Test/node_modules/discor
Error: Cannot find module 'node:events'
Require stack:
- /home/runner/Omega-Flowey-JS-Test/node_modules/discord.js/src/client/BaseClient.js
- /home/runner/Omega-Flowey-JS-Test/node_modules/discord.js/src/index.js
- /home/runner/Omega-Flowey-JS-Test/index.js
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:815:15)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:667:27)
    at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:887:19)
    at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:74:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/home/runner/Omega-Flowey-JS-Test/node_modules/discord.js/src/client/BaseClient.js:3:22)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:999:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1027:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:863:32)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:708:14)
    at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:887:19
```

Can someone tell me whats error? I'm very new at Discord.JS so I don't know anything that is error.

Comment: Did you get an errors when you ran `npm install` ?

Comment: I don't know, when I started it, it just instantly gives that error.
Like how the program just doesn't want to try to run and just gives an error

Answer (score 6):

Discord.js v13 requires Node.js v16.6. Replit only directly supports Node.js v12.16.1 (at the time of writing).

When using an older version of Node.js, you may see errors such as

- [Error: Cannot find module 'node:events'](https://stackoverflow.com/q/69489101/8289918)
- [ReferenceError: AbortController is not defined](https://stackoverflow.com/q/68693319/8289918)
- [SyntaxError: Unexpected token '?'](https://stackoverflow.com/q/69355690/8289918)

However, you can install a newer Node.js binary using the [node](https://www.npmjs.com/package/node) npm package.

Here's a minimal setup:

`package.json`

```json
{
  "name": "node.js-v16-on-replit-demo",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "dependencies": {
    "discord.js": "^13.2.0",
    "node": "^16.10.0"
  }
}
```

`.replit`

```
run = "npx node ."
```

`index.js`

```js
const Discord = require("discord.js")

// your code...
```

You can try this out with this [demo repl](https://replit.com/@cherryblossom00/Nodejs-v16-demo).

If you like, you can define a `start` npm script:

`package.json`

```json
{
  // ...
  "scripts": {
    "start": "node ."
  }
}
```

`.replit`

```
run = 'npm start'
```

There are also [plenty of resources online](https://www.google.com/search?q=replit+node.js+16) about Node.js v16 on Replit.

Comment: It works, but when I try to put any kind of code it will just make an error

Comment: You need to be a lot more specific than 'make an error'. Please edit your question to include the full details of error,

Comment: I just want to add that this will happen even when using v12, so you are forced to upgrade regardless

Comment: Link to a "cannot find module 'node:events' question": https://stackoverflow.com/q/69489101/15781079