# Getting a node:error error when running Discord bot online

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord.js

I'm getting this error when running my discord bot code online. This doesn't happen when I'm running it on VSCode and I'm not able to figure out why. How can I stop this error from happening?

```
RuntimeError: Cannot find module 'node:events'
Require stack:
- /opt/node_modules/discord.js/src/client/BaseClient.js

Error: Cannot find module 'node:events'
Require stack:
- /opt/node_modules/discord.js/src/client/BaseClient.js

The JSON output of the error is below.
{
  "error": {
    "type": "RuntimeError",
    "message": "Cannot find module 'node:events'\nRequire stack:\n- /opt/node_modules/discord.js/src/client/BaseClient.js",
    "stack": "Error: Cannot find module 'node:events'\nRequire stack:\n- /opt/node_modules/discord.js/src/client/BaseClient.js"
  }
}
```

Comment: Where are you trying to run your code? "Online" is way too vague; what hosting platform/etc.?

Comment: Hi, welcome to StackOverflow! What version of Node.js are you using? Discord.js v13 requires Node.js v16.6.

Comment: @solarshado I got the same error when running it on autocode.com and replit.com

Comment: @cherryblossom on Replit, I've downloaded Node.js 16.6 but when I'm typing out 'node --version' into the shell, it says v12.22.6

Comment: See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69462898/8289918)