# Error when requiring discordjs: "cannot find module 'node:events'"

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord.js

I'm trying to develop a bot to disagree. I installed the `npm install discord.js --save` library. But it is giving an error when importing it. How can I fix it?

Command: `node .`

```
internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:892
  throw err;
  ^

Error: Cannot find module 'node:events'
Require stack:
- C:\Users\Gobs\Desktop\blog3\node_modules\discord.js\src\client\BaseClient.js
- C:\Users\Gobs\Desktop\blog3\node_modules\discord.js\src\index.js
- C:\Users\Gobs\Desktop\blog3\main.js
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:889:15)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:745:27)
    at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:961:19)
    at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:92:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\Gobs\Desktop\blog3\node_modules\discord.js\src\client\BaseClient.js:3:22)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1072:14)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1101:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:937:32)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:778:12)
    at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:961:19) {
  code: 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND',
  requireStack: [
    'C:\\Users\\Gobs\\Desktop\\blog3\\node_modules\\discord.js\\src\\client\\BaseClient.js',
    'C:\\Users\\Gobs\\Desktop\\blog3\\node_modules\\discord.js\\src\\index.js',
    'C:\\Users\\Gobs\\Desktop\\blog3\\main.js'
  ]
}
```

#### JSON

```
{
    ...
    "main": "main.js",
    "scripts": {
    },
    "dependencies": {
        "discord.js": "^13.2.0"
    }
    ...
}
```

Comment: show the source code of your index and or main, where you're setting things up plz

Comment: Required node.js version for discord.js v13 is v16.6.

Answer (score 24):

The required Node.js version for *discord.js* is v16.6. Without it you could get errors such as

- AbortController is not defined
- Unexpected token '?'
- Cannot find module 'node:events'

Simply just upgrade to v16.6 and these errors will be fixed.