# error starting node discordjs, how i can start?

Tags: node.js, npm, discord.js, npm-install

Good, I apologize for the inconvenience, I would like to know if this has happened to someone, I am trying to run a bot in Ubuntu 18, but it does not start, I already installed everything as in Windows but for Ubuntu clearly.

In windows, the same bot works, but when I try to start it in Ubuntu, it throws me this error, I have already installed a thousand things on the machine that literally nothing to do with it.
If someone could help me or allow me where to read, I would be infinitely grateful.

```
root@ns533280:/home/Discord/Test# node index.js
module.js:487
throw err;
^

Error: Cannot find module 'node:events'
at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:485:15)
at Function.Module._load (module.js:437:25)
at Module.require (module.js:513:17)
at require (internal/module.js:11:18)
at Object.<anonymous> 
(/home/Discord/Test/node_modules/discord.js/src/client/BaseClient.js:3:22)
at Module._compile (module.js:569:30)
at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:580:10)
at Module.load (module.js:503:32)
at tryModuleLoad (module.js:466:12)
at Function.Module._load (module.js:458:3)
root@ns533280:/home/Discord/Test# node -v
v8.0.0
root@ns533280:/home/Discord/Test# npm -v
5.0.0
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [error when requiring discordjs - cannot find module 'node:events'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69489101/error-when-requiring-discordjs-cannot-find-module-nodeevents)

Answer (score 0):

### **How To Solve Error: Cannot find module 'node:events' Error?**

**To Solve Error:-**
Cannot find module 'node:events' Error Minimum required nodejs version is v16.6 in order to use discord.js. So You just need to update nodejs to v16.6. And Your error will be solved.

Comment: u are good! Thanks!!!

Comment: [@Zhenk](https://stackoverflow.com/users/14228154/zhenk) Good to know it works for you:)

Answer (score 0):

You use too old version of node.js. According to this [doc](https://www.npmjs.com/package/discord.js?source=post_page-----7b5fe27cb6fa----------------------) node 16.6.0 required. Just update your node.js version by install new or by nvm(for manage different node.js version on your PC).    [image]