# discord.js typescript error - missing index.ts when executing 'ts-node index.ts'

Tags: javascript, typescript, discord.js

I am creating a discord bot with discord.js and typescript but when I try to turn the bot on, using 'ts-node index.ts' this is the error I am given:

```c
Error: Cannot find module 'node:events'
Require stack:
- /home/ether0p12348/RainCrown/node_modules/discord.js/src/client/BaseClient.js
- /home/ether0p12348/RainCrown/node_modules/discord.js/src/index.js
- /home/ether0p12348/RainCrown/index.ts
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:815:15)
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename.sharedData.moduleResolveFilenameHook.installedValue [as _resolveFilename] (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/ts-node/node_modules/@cspotcode/source-map-support/source-map-support.js:679:30)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:667:27)
    at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:887:19)
    at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:74:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/home/ether0p12348/RainCrown/node_modules/discord.js/src/client/BaseClient.js:3:22)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:999:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1027:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:863:32)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:708:14) {
  code: 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND',
  requireStack: [
    '/home/ether0p12348/RainCrown/node_modules/discord.js/src/client/BaseClient.js',
    '/home/ether0p12348/RainCrown/node_modules/discord.js/src/index.js',
    '/home/ether0p12348/RainCrown/index.ts'
  ]
}
```

This is what I have in index.ts in the bot's root directory

```ts
const Discord = require('discord.js')

import DiscordJS, {Intents} from 'discord.js'
import dotenv from 'dotenv'
dotenv.config()

const client = new DiscordJS.Client({
    intents: [
        Intents.FLAGS.GUILDS,
        Intents.FLAGS.GUILD_MESSAGES,
    ]
})

client.on('ready', () => {
    console.log('RainCrown is ready!')
})

client.on('messageCreate', (message) => {
    if (message.content === 'ping') {
        message.reply({
            content: 'pong',
        })
    }
})

client.login(process.env.TOKEN)
```

all I have in ".env" is my token *(edited)*

my 'ls' output: `index.ts  node_modules  package.json  package-lock.json  tsconfig.json`

If anyone could guide me on what steps I should take to resolve this error, that would be greatly appreciated.

ps: I am using a raspberry pi with the ubuntu OS to host this bot

Comment: Please post your code and the error message as text.

Comment: what does your file structure look like? are you running `ts-node index.ts` in the same folder as you've saved the `index.ts` file?

Comment: After updating some errors in my code, I forgot to reenter the correct directory. Thanks! There is a new error though, that I find to be more confusing. updated the error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Borecjeborec1 said, I just had to update my node.js to 16.6.
This is the document that helped my achieve this:

https://computingforgeeks.com/how-to-install-node-js-on-ubuntu-debian/

The solution that worked for me was installing 'nvm' and installing v16 from there (solution 2 on document).

Answer (score 1):

You are propably not using the right node version. Try upgrading it. The newer discordjs needs atleasr v16.6.
Check out this post [error when requiring discordjs - cannot find module 'node:events'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69489101/error-when-requiring-discordjs-cannot-find-module-nodeevents).
I faced the same issue on 32 bit machine where i have problems installing node16, so I used the *older* discordjs version.

Comment: I am using a raspberry pi running ubuntu aarch64. Would it be best to use discord.js or discord.js.old? Does discord.js.old require a different js syntax or can I keep that code I have already written?

Comment: Of course you can just upgrade the nodejs version. If you are on UBUNTU, it should be this commands ```sudo npm cache clean -f``` ```sudo npm install -g n ```
```sudo n stable```