# How can I fix this "missing module" error (node.js/discord.js)?

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord.js

Here's the code, I was trying to run a discord bot file.

```
$ node index.js
internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:883
  throw err;
  ^

Error: Cannot find module 'node:events'
Require stack:
- /path/bot/node_modules/discord.js/src/client/BaseClient.js
- /path/bot/node_modules/discord.js/src/index.js
- /path/bot/index.js
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:880:15)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:725:27)
    at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:952:19)
    at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:88:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/path/bot/node_modules/discord.js/src/client/BaseClient.js:3:22)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1063:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1092:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:928:32)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:769:14)
    at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:952:19) {
  code: 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND',
  requireStack: [
    '/path/bot/node_modules/discord.js/src/client/BaseClient.js',
    '/path/bot/node_modules/discord.js/src/index.js',
    '/path/bot/index.js'
  ]
}
```

What module would be missing? I haven't really fiddled around with node.js much, or discord.js, so I have no idea what could be going wrong.
Plz help :)

Comment: Ah, no one knows...

Comment: Which version of Node.js is running on your machine and which discord.js version are you using?

Comment: node version 14.16.0 npm version 8.4.1 and discord.js version 13.6.0
(sry that I didn't respond fast)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [error when requiring discordjs - cannot find module 'node:events'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69489101/error-when-requiring-discordjs-cannot-find-module-nodeevents)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're using discord.js version `13+` you need to upgrade to Node.js version 16.+. Otherwise you won't be able to run the bot

Simply visit [Node.js](https://nodejs.org/en/) and either install the LTS (recommended) version or the current