# My deploycommands.js file is not running when I use a script and throwing an error when I run it manually

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord.js

In my discord bot, I'm trying to run 2 files in the start script: `index.js` and `deploycommands.js`. It is running `index.js` properly, but not running `deploycommands.js`.

When I run `deploycommands.js` manually using `node deploycommands.js` it throws an error, which I have provided below.

`deploycommands.js` (The file is in the root directory)

```
//Imports
const { REST } = require('@discordjs/rest');
const { Routes } = require('discord-api-types/v9');
const fs = require('fs');

const rest = new REST({ version: '9' }).setToken(process.env.token);

const commands = [];

const guilds = [
  '833289549341523998',
    '804731876950147122',
    '793019059691192370',
    '853617621547352104',
    '872713876284792892',
  '882096964295082004',
  '851070792196030524',
  '904751148404203522',
]


//Pushing command files to 'commands' array
fs.readdirSync("./commands").forEach(dir => {
  fs.readdir(`./commands/${dir}`, (err, files) => {
    if (err) {
      throw err
      return
    }

    const commandFiles = files.filter(file => file.endsWith(".js"));

    if (commandFiles.length <= 0) return

    commandFiles.forEach(file => {
      const command = require(`./commands/${dir}/${file}`);
      try {
        commands.push(command)
      } catch (err) {
        return console.log(`[ERROR] - ${error}`);
      }
    });
  });
});


//Pushing the array to guild commands
for (const guild of guilds) {

  (async () => {
      try {
          console.log('Started refreshing guild commands.');

          await rest.put(
              Routes.applicationGuildCommands(process.env.clientId, guild),
              { body: commands },
          );

          console.log('Successfully reloaded guild commands.');
      } catch (error) {
          console.error(error);
      }
  })();
}

//Pushing the array to global commands
(async () => {
      try {
          console.log('Started refreshing global commands.');

          await rest.put(
              Routes.applicationCommands(process.env.clientId),
              { body: commands },
          );

          console.log('Successfully reloaded global commands.');
      } catch (error) {
          console.error(error);
      }
  })();
```

The script I'm using to run the bot:

```
{
    "scripts": {
        "index": "node .",
        "deploycommands": "node deploycommands.js",
        "start": "npm run index && npm run deploycommands",
}
}
```

I'm running the bot with `npm start`

The error thrown when I try to run `deploycommands.js` manually

```
/home/runner/MultiBot/node_modules/@discordjs/rest/dist/lib/RequestManager.js:66
        const hash = this.hashes.get(`${request.method}:${routeID.bucketRoute}`) ?? `Global(${request.method}:${routeID.bucketRoute})`;
                                                                                  ^

SyntaxError: Unexpected token '?'
    at wrapSafe (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:915:16)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:963:27)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1027:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:863:32)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:708:14)
    at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:887:19)
    at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:74:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/home/runner/MultiBot/node_modules/@discordjs/rest/dist/index.js:7:22)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:999:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1027:10)
```

Edit:

The error is caused by the first import in `deploycommands.js`: `const { REST } = require('@discordjs/rest');`.
When I comment that line out, it throws an error on line 6 saying `REST is not defined`, which is expected

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to solve error "SyntaxError: Unexpected token '?'"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68692038/how-to-solve-error-syntaxerror-unexpected-token)

Comment: @MrMythical I get an error

  https://gist.github.com/TechPro424/7daa6121d52d50c1bd441f164f8433b5

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From my experimentation, I have discovered that only the shell in replit is updated when you try to update the node version. Hence why it displays v12 on the `Console` tab and hence this error.

Answer (score 0):

You could try the `--save-exact` flag when installing the package to force node package manager to store the exact module version.

`npm install node@16.13.1 --save-dev --save-exact`

Comment: Was able to keep node in the version I wanted, but unfortunately keeping node in that version did not solve my issue. But thanks for the help though! :)