# Unexpected token '?' in Rest

Tags: discord.js

I'm trying to add slash commands to my discord bot using Discord.js and Rest but I keep getting an unexpected token somewhere in rest. Could anybody help me?

**When I run:**

```
const { SlashCommandBuilder, Routes } = require('discord.js');
const { REST } = require('@discordjs/rest');
var clientId = //myClientId
var guildId = //myGuildId

const commands = [
    new SlashCommandBuilder().setName('ping').setDescription('Replies with pong!')
]
    commands.map(command => command.toJSON());

const rest = new REST({ version: '10' }).setToken(process.env.TOKEN);

(async () => {
    try {
        console.log('Started refreshing application (/) commands.');

        await rest.put(
        Routes.applicationCommands(clientId),
        { body: commands },
    );

        console.log('Successfully reloaded application (/) commands.');
    } catch (error) {
        console.error(error);
    }
})();
```

**I Get:**

```
/home/runner/TinkerTank/node_modules/@discordjs/rest/dist/lib/CDN.cjs:53
      extension: extension ?? "png"
                            ^

SyntaxError: Unexpected token '?'
    at wrapSafe (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:915:16)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:963:27)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1027:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:863:32)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:708:14)
    at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:887:19)
    at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:74:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/home/runner/TinkerTank/node_modules/@discordjs/rest/dist/index.cjs:5:13)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:999:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1027:10)
```

If somebody could help me out that would be great.

Comment: The nullish coalescing operator (??) Was added to nodejs in v14, update your NodeJS version

Answer (score 0):

maby this will help you. `npm install node@16.13.1 --save-dev --save-exact`
For me, this solved the problem.

I found this [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70284956/my-deploycommands-js-file-is-not-running-when-i-use-a-script-and-throwing-an-err)