Running old apirest & give error node_modules/pirates
I use hapijs and pm2, and when i do "pm2 start app.js" and pm2 log server i give this:
0|server  | SyntaxError: Unexpected token '?'
0|server  |     at wrapSafe (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:915:16)
0|server  |     at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:963:27)
0|server  |     at Module._compile (/var/www/vhosts/mydomain.com/api.mydomain.com/deploy/prod/node_modules/pirates/lib/index.js:117:24)
0|server  |     at Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1027:10)
0|server  |     at Object.newLoader [as .js] (/var/www/vhosts/mydomain.com/api.mydomain.com/deploy/prod/node_modules/pirates/lib/index.js:121:7)
0|server  |     at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:863:32)
0|server  |     at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:708:14)
0|server  |     at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:887:19)
0|server  |     at Module.Hook._require.Module.require (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/pm2/node_modules/require-in-the-middle/index.js:101:39)
0|server  |     at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:74:18)
0|server  |     at Object.<anonymous> (/var/www/vhosts/mydomain.com/api.mydomain.com/deploy/prod/node_modules/@hapi/hapi/lib/index.js:3:16)
0|server  |     at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:999:30)
0|server  |     at Module._compile (/var/www/vhosts/mydomain.com/api.mydomain.com/deploy/prod/node_modules/pirates/lib/index.js:117:24)
0|server  |     at Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1027:10)
...

i dont know how can i start to fix.

It's likely your nodejs version is not new enough. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68692038/how-to-solve-error-syntaxerror-unexpected-token
